# How to count sort comparison

Tags: algorithms, sorting, measurement

When it is said that this sort has M number of comparisons what does it mean?

As an example:

```
procedure bubbleSort( A : list of sortable items )
   n = length(A)
   repeat 
     swapped = false
     for i = 1 to n-1 inclusive do
       if A[i-1] > A[i] then
         swap( A[i-1], A[i] )
         swapped = true
       end if
     end for
   until not swapped
end procedure
```

Has

```
for i = 1 to n-1
```

or

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < n-1; i++)
```

is this comparison (`i < n-1`) taken into account?

Or in merge sort, beside the main comparison:

```
        if (v[first1]<v[first2])
```

at the end of a used function it is written:

```
    while (first1 <= last1)
        temp[index++] = v[first1++];
    while (first2 <= last2)
        temp[index++] = v[first2++];
    for (index = first; index <= last; index++)
        v[index] = temp[index];
```

Are these comparisons are taken into account?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/117304/basic-premise-on-counting-sort-how-is-k-related-to-to-big-oh

Comment: @JayElston, Could you explain how that question answers about what commands to be taken into account? btw, I do not care about big o. I need exact number of comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you find a statement like "M number of comparisons" about sorting algorithms in literature, the author typically means the **number of comparisons between the sorted elements**, not the comparisons of something like loop indexes. So if you are asked this in a university assignment, I would guess that this is the number which is meant (but to make that clear, if you give an answer, why not *add a note describing exactly what you counted*).

In fact, this assumes that the predominant operations in a sorting algorithm are comparisons and "swaps", and that there are not more loop iterations than comparisons between the sorted elements. When you assume the latter, for calculating Big-O it is irrelevant if you count the "loop index comparisons" or not.

Furthermore, note that a term like "exact number of comparisons" instead of "O(number of comparisons)" makes only sense for a **specific implementation** of an algorithm, not "for an algorithm" in general. So when you try to compare the number of comparisons of *your implementation* of bubble sort to a different implementation from a different author, you have to make sure you do not compare apples and oranges. That is why comparisons in terms of "Big-O" makes more sense when comparing algorithms on a theoretical level.

However, from a more practical point of view, counting the exact "number of comparisons" (or swaps) will indeed make sense when it comes to speed comparisons of specific sorting implementations on real-world data.